# undefined attribute name data-placeholder

Tags: php, html, forms, yii, jquery-chosen

I have tried searching these two problems and some suggestions were to not include forms inside tables so I have since removed all of my tables as apparently this is not correct method for formatting your website? Another suggestion was that my jquery wasn't linking in correctly which I think is the problem because the forms are not behaving as they are supposed to.

I'm using chosen jquery http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and MVC yii framework.

Here is me trying to link my java files in

```
<script src="./assets/chosenjquery/js/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./assets/chosenjquery/js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="./assets/chosenjquery/css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and here is the form I'm having the issue with receiving a warning undefined attribute name (data-placeholder) on the line where I have `<select data-placeholder="Select a Country.." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">`

```
<!-- Select Country --> 
<p>
<label for="selectCountry">Select a Country:</label>
<form id="selectCountry" name="selectCountry">
    <select data-placeholder="Select a Country.." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option> 
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
    <option value="England">England</option> 
    </select>
</form>
</p>
```

The form is supposed to be a drop down menu with a search included that displays matching values in the list. See http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ where it changes the standard select menu. Mine however displays a standard list which makes me think there something wrong with how I'm linking in my java files. This works in a previous project :/

Comment: your select doesn't have a `name`

Comment: and "data-placeholder" is not a valid attribute for the select

Comment: @Dagon See the provided link. OPs code is correct.

Comment: just because some js  uses it does not make it valid html

Comment: @dagon data-* is valid in html5

Comment: dam that htm5, i'm so out of date with its changes :(

Comment: you also are going to have to include in the chosen.jquery.min.js (after the jquery include)

Comment: Try only `placeholder`

Comment: What is the problem? You seem to be referring to some error messages but you do not quote them or cite their source. And you refer to functional problems ("not behaving as they are supposed to") without describing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form id="selectCountry" name="selectCountry">
<p>
<label for="selectCountry">Select a Country:</label>
    <select data-placeholder="Select a Country.." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option> 
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
    <option value="England">England</option> 
    </select>
</p>
</form>
```

Your form was invaild since he was in `p` / `pre` tag.

About `data-placeholder`, have you tried `Placeholder` only?

Comment: Thanks alot that fixed the problem of the form tag being in the wrong place. I have tried using just Placeholder but I still get the same error, is there something wrong with how I have linked my java files?

Comment: I'm using Mozilla Firefox latest version and I'm reusing code that already worked for me in a previous file. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Near my answer there is a V symbol, click it

Comment: Are you looking for a Yii friendly answer, or something different?  This does not really follow Yii style.